# How to position the elements in a custom action bar layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I need to develop a custom layout for the action bar in Android.

I'm now stuck because I have no clue how to **calculate the available space** for my custom layout.

[image]

In the image, the red part is **my custom layout**, the blue part is the space occupied by the **action buttons**.

Clearly I need to know/calculate the size of the red part to be able to correctly position the elements in my custom action bar (for example center the title in the window or make sure not to overflow in the blue part).

How can I achieve this?

I couldn't find useful examples or a clear API in the Android documentation. 
I think that anyone using the custom action bar layout must be facing this kind of problem, I'm a bit confused.

Or am I supposed not to use action buttons in this case? Perhaps I'm supposed to replicate the action buttons by myself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ToolBar instead of ActionBar. It will give you a lot more control over ActionBar elements than ActionBar.

Here is a simple tutorial about how to replace ActionBar with ToolBar and how you can customise it.

[Material ToolBar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Possibilities are endless with ToolBar but my recommendation is to don't overdo anything.

Comment: yes, after some experimenting the Toolbar is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion try to use the entire action bar by your custom layout. So that you can arrange all the things use it as a fragment inside a framelayout for all your screens so that the code can be reused for all your layouts.

Comment: it is a good suggestion, however it is a workaround. Using a toolbar is definitely a better option.